# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/ajax4jsf/resource/InternetResourceBuilder 

Tags: jsf, tomcat, jsf-2, richfaces

My application, which uses JSF 2 and Richfaces 3.3.3, and mojarra 2.0.2 works fine on Glassfish 3.1 , but whenever i port it on Tomcat 7.0.10, every time i get one or the other problem. 
It started with failure to detect jsf_core.tld , followed by some JSF rendering issue and finally this one.
Lastly i found some which i m mentioning here and which i cannot find a way around to fix.

```
Mar 31, 2011 8:57:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! org/ajax4jsf/resource/InternetResourceBuilder
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:294)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4651)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5149)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! org/ajax4jsf/resource/InternetResourceBuilder
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:357)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:226)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/ajax4jsf/resource/InternetResourceBuilder
        at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.ChameleonRenderKitFactory.<init>(ChameleonRenderKitFactory.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinder.java:586)
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinder.java:472)
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.access$400(FactoryFinder.java:139)
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:796)
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:306)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:294)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:213)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:338)
        ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 1):

You've the RichFaces impl JAR file, but not the RichFaces API JAR in the runtime classpath.

The stacktrace is evidence of this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/ajax4jsf/resource/InternetResourceBuilder
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.ChameleonRenderKitFactory.<init>(ChameleonRenderKitFactory.java:62)
```

The `at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.ChameleonRenderKitFactory` line indicates that this particular class was successfully loaded and executed (otherwise it wouldn't have shown up as an `at xxx` in the stacktrace at all). This class is part of RichFaces impl JAR file. The `InternetResourceBuilder` is in turn part of the RichFaces API JAR file. This is apparently missing in the runtime classpath. At least, that's just exactly what the exception is telling us.

Answer (score 0):

From the exception it seems that Richfaces cannot be found. Put the jar in your classpath (for Tomcat WEB-INF/lib or WEB-INF/classes) and try again.

Comment: i am firm that all those jars are in my classpath (richfaces-impl-jsf2.3.3.3.Final.jar,richfaces-ui-3.3.3.Final.jar,richfaces-api-3.3.3.Final.jar), and then these problem are coming . (i have dived inside WAR and found all those jars inside web-inf/lib folder)

Comment: Do you find it in the deployment folder of tomcat too?